# Android : Best Way to Call Retrofit API on TextChange

Tags: android, web-services, caching, search, retrofit

I have created one demo to get a list of data from the server using Retrofit. I have 50000+ records.

Now what I have implemented,

- Call API after 3 characters written in SearchView
- After that, call API on each character press event.

A problem that I am facing:

- Too slow to load items,
- Too much API requests on every keypress (any solution to make it more effective)

I have heard about [**Retrofit Caching**](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified) that may help me but don't know much more about it.

Any other solution to make it more efficient.

Comment: `After that, call API on each character press event.` , why? I would wait until some sort of idle time before sending the request. `I have 50000+ records.` Pagination?

Comment: You can use Kotlin Coroutines for searching.

Comment: @Blackbelt Yeah, one way is that to wait for while and call API. Main problem is that I have to search it from 50k+ records

Comment: @Jaymin I am working with Java

Comment: no rxjava I assume?

Comment: @Blackbelt No, I simply use Retrofit with Gson.

Comment: rxjava with debounce will be best suited for your requirement

Comment: I think We have RxJava for this. You can do all at the same time with the help of RxJava. Check out this article https://medium.com/@kishankr.maurya/handling-searchview-with-rxjava-32c60380f326

Comment: `Too much API requests on every keypress (any solution to make it more effective)` I would start addressing this. You could have a Handler with a post delayed and cancel the current runnable if the users press a new character before a predefined timeout

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Thanks for that link. I will go through it.

Comment: use `Filter`: the docs say *"Filtering operations performed by calling filter(CharSequence) or filter(CharSequence, android.widget.Filter.FilterListener) are performed asynchronously. When these methods are called, a filtering request is posted in a request queue and processed later. Any call to one of these methods will cancel any previous non-executed filtering request."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use with rxjava

create an extension function for `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
fun AutoCompleteTextView.addRxTextWatcher(): Observable<String?> {

    val flowable = Observable.create<String?> {
        addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                it.onNext(s?.toString())
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }
        })
    }

    return flowable
}
```

and for `AutocompleteTextView` add debounce strategy , Here I added time of 400 millisecond , If there is no user input for 400ms then the api request will go . change time according to your requirement

```
 autocompleteTextView.addRxTextWatcher()
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(it)) {
                    //DO api request
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In java I also think the best way is to Use RxJava and RxBinding as follows

```
 compositeDisposable.add(RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchEditText)
            .skipInitialValue()
            .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<TextViewTextChangeEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(TextViewTextChangeEvent textViewTextChangeEvent) {

adapter.getFilter().filter(textViewTextChangeEvent.getText());
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The value seached "+ textViewTextChangeEvent);
                 //   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The error gotten from search: "+ e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }));
}
```